# Would like to filter a movie check box list in haml/rails so that when I select a rating! its content is displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and have been attempting to filter a check box list so that upon selecting check box the selected movie is displayed! Currently I have the movie form populated with the ratings that chose in my index as shown below:

```
= form_tag movies_path, :method => :get do
  Include:
  - @all_ratings.each do |rating|
    = rating
    = check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]"
  = submit_tag 'Refresh'
```

In my model movie.rb view I put the following;

```
def self.all_ratings
  Array['G','PG','PG-13','R','NC-17']
end
```

And in movie controller I have the following;

```
def index
 @all_ratings = Movie.all_ratings
```

I am required to replace the movie.all with movie.find which I tried doing ended with NilClass error! Currently the form is displayed with the selected paramaters however I would it to dynamic in that it can display a rating or ratings upon clicking on check box! I hope this makes sense... I tried various ways to filter this form ie updating index file like; params[:rating].include?(rating) got a Nilclass error!!!! All efforts rendered in rectifying this issue will be most appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what your doubt is but i think in index u do like this .. Movie.find(params[:id]) where id = movie id .

Comment: @Sp1rs thanks for your feedback, do I apply the above modification in my index or controller? please clarify!!

Comment: Index action in your controller

Comment: Thanks will let you know....

Comment: Added the above modification to my controller.rb as stated above and got this error:/movies_controller.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
      @all_ratings = Movie.find(params[:id]) where id = movie id

Comment: no no . just do this .. @all_ratings=Movie.find(params[:id])
please paste the model code movie.rb

Comment: Thanks sp1rs for your feedback, will let know if it works..

Comment: Pasted the code into my model movie.rb got error:undefined local variable or method `params' for #<Class:0xb695ba1c>

Comment: I wonder what I am doing wrong! I have got the frame work set right as described previously!! but keep getting these errors... Filtering these choices is sooo daunting.

Comment: Is there anyone out there that point me in the right direction! cmon guys...

Comment: Please paste the model code ...., and i said that paste the line @all_ratings=Movie.find(params[:id]) in your index controller

Comment: Hi Sp1rs, I pasted the line into my controller.rb and got this error  ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in MoviesController#index

Couldn't find Movie without an ID,

Comment: app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:10:in `index', So I will try pasting into my index.html.haml file..which happens to house the frame work for the check boxes.

Comment: Qn: Should I modify or replace the line - @all_ratings.each do |rating| with @all_ratings=Movie.find(params[:id]) in my index.html.haml file?

Comment: Can you please paste the params values ?

Comment: Hi in my controller right above the (def index)I have the following method def show
    id = params[:id] # retrieve movie ID from URI route
    @movie = Movie.find(id) # look up movie by unique ID
    # will render app/views/movies/show.<extension> by default
  end   By params values do you mean values in my model, the ratings?

Comment: Sp1rs, Where would locate these param values?

Comment: My param values are Array['G','PG','PG-13','R','NC-17'] I placed these in movie.rb file

Comment: I pasted that code in my index controller/movie.rb like so....class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
def Movie.all_ratings
    array['G','PG','PG-13','R','NC-17']
    @all_ratings=Movie.find(params[:id])
    
end   got this error 

app/models/movie.rb:3:in `all_ratings'
app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:10:in `index'

Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "ratings"=>{"PG"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Refresh"}

Comment: params is a default hash value which store information like  "utf8"=>"✓", "ratings"=>{"PG"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Refresh"   this ... and it changes its value after every other call . It's(params) value will be different in index and when you call show it's(params) value will be changed . 

Please paste the abouve code that i told you in your index action .

Comment: By index action do you mean the movie.rb or the controller.rb?

Comment: I pasted @all_ratings=Movie.find(params[:id]) in my movies_controller more specifically in the def show method! upon refreshing i got no errors, but when I went ahead to select check my rating box and hit refresh page refreshed but the selected rating wasn’t isolated!!